# drupal_mail - Need to Remove $_POST

Tags: email, drupal, parameters

I am new to the drupal_mail function and need help. The code I have works, but I want to get rid of the $_POST parameter to limit my security holes.

I don't know how to get the posted variables without using the $_POST parameter, and ideally, I would like to single each parameter out to put a custom label on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    function revenue_calculations() {

    $block = array();
$a = $b = $c = '';
    $errors = array();
    $output = '';
if (isset($_POST)) {

    if (isset($_POST['a'])) $a = (int) round($_POST['a']);
    if (isset($_POST['b'])) $b = (int) round($_POST['b']);
    if (isset($_POST['c'])) $c = (int) round($_POST['c']);

    if (!empty($a) && !empty($b)&& !empty($c)) {

        $calc1 = $a * ($b/100);
        $calc2 = $calc1 * ($c/100);
        $calc3 = $calc2 * .65 * .99;
        $display = '$'.number_format($calc3,2);

////// throw in a drupal_mail send, with the form details  //////
function calculator_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
switch ($key) {
case 'calculation':
  $message['subject'] = t('CALCULATION DONE');
  foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
    $message['body'][] = $key.': '.check_plain($value);
  }
  break;    
  }
}

drupal_mail('calculator', 'calculation', 'xxx@xxx.com', language_default(), $_POST);


        $output = "Your result is $display;

    }

}
$output .= revenue_calculator();
return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate `$_POST[]`, you can post JSON data as opposed to form encoded data.

This can be done in a variety of ways, depending on how you are posting your data. I assume drupal sends a form's result to the script, but if you post using the JSON method most commonly used by jQuery and other javascript implementations, you can decode it as so:

```
<?php
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");

$obj = json_decode($foo, true);
$myVar = $obj -> a;
```

This is the "superior" way of posting to PHP nowadays, as POST has become a bit of a insecure outlet.

Honestly, if your code does proper input sanitation, you shouldn't need to worry about $_POST. If it's drupal, and a later version, I can assure you that they have patched all the security holes. **$_POST[] itself is not vulnerable, rather, the blind trust of values coming from it is dangerous.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not quite sure how to implement it in my specific situation - I am not that familiar with JSON data - but I will look into this.